# Why can't I install Gluon JavaFX on Eclipse 2019-09?

Tags: java, eclipse, guava, gluon, gluon-mobile

I want to install Gluon JavaFX plugin on Eclipse 2019-09. But it won't!

Here is the error code when I try to install from Market Place in Eclipse.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Gluon Plug-in for Eclipse 2.6.0.v20180424-0818 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.group 2.6.0.v20180424-0818)
  Missing requirement: Gluon Plug-in for Eclipse 2.6.0.v20180424-0818 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin 2.6.0.v20180424-0818) requires 'osgi.bundle; com.google.guava [15.0.0,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Gluon Plug-in for Eclipse 2.6.0.v20180424-0818 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.group 2.6.0.v20180424-0818)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin [2.6.0.v20180424-0818,2.6.0.v20180424-0818]
```

I need to have `osgi.bundle` and `com.google.guava`, but where should I install these? Inside eclipse, or in my operative system? I'm using Ubuntu Linux and OpenJDK 8.

Yes! I have tried to search on plugin inside Market Place inside Eclipse IDE, but I don't know what to select.

Comment: Assuming this is the complete error message, at least one part of the Gluon plug-in is missing (the feature `com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.group` exists and requires `com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin` of the same version that is missing). Contact the Gluon team and ask them to fix their update site.

Comment: @howlger this have been like this for 1.5 year from now. The last working version of Eclipse with this Plugin is Eclipse 2018-06.

Comment: The Eclipse Marketplace does not host the plug-ins itself but refers to update site URLs. Assuming this is the complete error message, something is missing on the Gluon update site. If it is not the complete error message, the `com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin` might be incompatible to the current Eclipse version. In both cases, please report the issue with the full error message to the Gluon team.